# Dual boot Ubuntu 22.10 and Win11 no longer working after win11 2022 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 22.10, windows-11

I have been running 22.10 for a while now, but recently I booted into win11 through the boot menu in bios. Win11 wanted to update a bunch of things, which i allowed.

After finishing all the updates and restarting win11, everything was updated. However, when I went to restart and load ubuntu 22.10, I can only boot 22.10 via the boot menu in bios.

I tried boot-repair, and there were some changes made, but that does not load the grub menu. Previously, ubuntu would boot unless I pressed f11 to bring up the quick boot menu (Micro-star mainboard).

This is the upload from boot-repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J6PFzrjpgW/

Does any one know how I can get grub to load by default?

Comment: Put the grub EFI entry before the Windows one with either efibootmgr or the UEFI settings of your computer. Fix the partition type on your 1n1p6 root to be 8300, not an EFI System type, and remove the boot,esp flags. Try a purge to clean up all the linux kernels with the "rc" at the beginning of the line from your paste, they have only been partially removed.

Comment: I am  trying to work through your recommendations.

Does this look better?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wv528vRJHS/

Comment: Yes, grub is now first in the bootorder, so it should boot the grub menu for you to choose the Os.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not happen.

`britt@britt-ryzen:~$ efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Hard Drive
Boot0004* ubuntu
`

Though it seems like efibootmgr says grub should boot, the computer still boots into win11.

Comment: Windows at 0000 got put first again (from your last paste with 0004 first).  Locked bootorder.  If you'd used efibootmgr for the switch, try using the UEFI settings/BIOS boot order. Try setting a supervisor password to unlock the order.  Try a windows powershell/admin bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi  That last worked for me with a complaint about not finding the default bootloader.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the bios and then changed some settings so that Grub now loads.

Comment: Good to hear.  You may answer your own question, and if upvoted, accept it after a few days.